# No SpringApplication sources have been defined. Either override the configure method or add an @Configuration annotation

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, war

I have a spring boot project, before this I always package it to a jar file and run it as this:
**java -jar myjar.jar**
And now I want to convert it to a war package and deploy it into tomcat. I followed this article:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging
but when I tried to deploy it into tomcat, I got the error:

```
2017-02-09 17:26:05.159 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  Service - Root context already created (using as parent).
09-Feb-2017 17:26:05.175 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SpringApplication sources have been defined. Either override the configure method or add an @Configuration annotation
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:124)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 10 more

09-Feb-2017 17:26:05.190 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive ***\apache-tomcat-8.0.39\webapps\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone who can help me for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show your main application code

Comment: Hi @Strelok, I have pasted my code in my ticket, please check it, thank you.

Comment: Is you configure method called?

Comment: Hi @Strelok, yes, I added some logs in configure method, and then I tried to deploy the war package into tomcat, I can see the logs in the screen, so I think the configure method is called.

Comment: Try to replace the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`
and `@ComponentScan` annotations with just `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @Strelok I replaced it and tried again, but got the same error. :(

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have two classes extending 'SpringBootServletInitializer' in same package where spring boot scans. Even removing  @SpringBootApplication or @ComponentScan of one of the classes does not work. Leaving only one class and after compiling it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Add @SpringBootApplication or @Configuration TeacService class it will work fine for me just check with that reply me if it wont work for you.

Answer (score -2):

Since mine was deployed on the company's platform, my problem was solved because the project's packet extraction address was incorrect